# Python: running docker containers with sh and handling UTF-8 decoding errors

Tags: python, jenkins, docker, utf-8, subprocess

I have a Python program that is directly executed by Jenkins. This program uses the [`sh`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sh%20%60sh%60) library to execute a docker container, via this function. Note that it is an important feature of this function that it display the subprocess's output as it executes:

```
def run_command(*args, **kwargs):

    # pass the parent stream 'tty' state to the command:
    tty_in = sys.stdin.isatty()
    tty_out = sys.stdout.isatty()

    run = sh.Command(args[0])
    try:
        for line in run(args[1:], _err=sys.stdout, _iter=True, _tty_in=tty_in, _tty_out=tty_out):
            sys.stdout.write(line)
            sys.stdout.flush()
```

As per the comments, `docker run` requires a TTY for input, so the keyword argument `_tty_in` is set to match whatever the state of `stdin` is. However when running under Jenkins, it is `False`.

However the issue is around UTF-8 encoded error messages from programs running within the container such as `cp`. This results in errors such as:

```
cp: cannot stat \xe2\x80\x98filename...
```

It turns out those three bytes are utf-8 encoding for a special "quote" character that cp likes to use when the locale is UTF-8. If I set the locale to "C" manually before running `cp` directly, I can see that it uses normal ascii instead.

When my Python script encounters these errors, it dies with the following:

```
Exception in thread Thread-10:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 763, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sh.py", line 1484, in output_thread
    done = stream.read()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sh.py", line 1974, in read
    self.write_chunk(chunk)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sh.py", line 1949, in write_chunk
    self.should_quit = self.process_chunk(chunk)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sh.py", line 1847, in process
    handler.write(chunk)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/codecs.py", line 351, in write
    data, consumed = self.encode(object, self.errors)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 16: ordinal not in range(128)
```

This suggests to me that the `sh` module is expecting ascii output from the subprocess, but is receiving UTF-8 and is unable to decode it.

I found the `_encoding` and `_decode_errors` options for `sh` and although these do seem to affect the locale that `cp` sees when run directly by `sh`, it does not appear to translate correctly for programs running within the docker container. However it does allow the program to continue as the decoding errors are skipped rather than raising an exception.

I would prefer to understand the situation better and implement a proper solution. Can anyone explain what is actually going on here, step by step (Jenkins > Python > sh > Docker > Bash)

I'm using Python 2.7.12 with Jenkins 2.33.

Comment: text `UnicodeDecodeError: '` mostly means that console/terminal doesn't use `UTF-8` or Python doesn't know it and it uses `encode('ascii')` instead of `encode('utf-8')` so you have to do it manually when you send string to console.

Comment: BTW: always put **FULL** error message (Traceback) in **QUESTION**. There are other usefull information, ie. which line makes problem.

Comment: @furas thanks, I've edited to add full traceback.

Comment: The issue I have is that it works fine when run directly from a terminal, but not when run by Jenkins. So if the Python code is to do something special, it needs to know that it is running under Jenkins, and what I don't understand is what must be changing in this environment, so that the python program can detect it and act accordingly. Again, it all works fine when run from my terminal.

Comment: Also, this error is happening when *reading* output from a sub-process - I'm not sending any strings to the console.

Comment: check source code of [sh](https://github.com/amoffat/sh/blob/master/sh.py) and you will see that `Command()` has option [encoding](https://github.com/amoffat/sh/blob/master/sh.py#L983) - maybe it resolve problem - try `Command(args[0], encoding='utf-8')`

Comment: or rather `run(args[1:], ..., _encoding='utf-8')`

Comment: @furas Yep, I've seen that option (I mentioned it in my question). This only seems to affect the encoding of text emitted via `stdout` or `stderr` - i.e. whether to output ASCII or UTF-8 text to the input of a subprocess. It doesn't appear (by looking at the code) to affect the locale that the subprocess is executed within. And my testing suggests it doesn't either.

Comment: The key thing, I suspect, is that this works 100% fine when run from a local terminal, and breaks 100% when run from Jenkins. Therefore I suspect it's related to the Jenkins environment or the options set on the pipes that Jenkins uses to spawn processes (if that can affect a subprocess's locale - I don't know enough about that). Jenkins doesn't allocate a TTY for the subprocesses as far as I can tell, so that might be relevant.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem when running python script in docker container.

I solved the following procedure.

(Step 1) add the following line in Dockerfile before running python command

```
ENV LANG C.UTF-8
```